# why i am not getting facebook comment moderator on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Why i am not able to get moderator view on my website .This is what i have done:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <%--  <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:6703/facebookcomments/Default.aspx" />--%>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="myfacebookId"/>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MyApplicationId";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:6703/facebookcomments/Default.aspx" data-width="470"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

also in comment moderation setting i set as "**let me approve each comment before it appears**".I am myself as application developer and admin. Why Logging with my facebook id i am not able to see the moderator. also i am not getting any notification in comment moderation tool settings. Is because i am using localhost it is not running? please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method:

Put this in you Document in the head section:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jayeshjain24ec" /> //username of moderater
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.something.com/" />
```

---

step 1) Go to this url : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

step 2) Enter your URL and click on debug.
In case if there is anything to be corrected,it will be mentioned here.

---

step 3)Correct all the warnings.Check the Scraped URL link at the bottom.Make sure it gets all the required Meta tags.

You will get a moderation option on your website once everything is ok.

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION:

Give yourself admin rights for the app(there is an option in settings).

go to this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue